# How to replace random values with function values?

Tags: matlab, matrix, visualization

In MATLAB, I have a matrix of size mxn which is decided by the user input.

At the moment, the matrix displays colour-mapped random values. I would now like to replace those values with a sine function.

I have the follwing bit of code, but I cant seem to figure out why I can't pass it to my main function.

The main function contain the variables and the timer functions which call this code.

```
function window_timer(obj, event, rows, cols)
imgh = get(obj,'UserData');
myMat = get(imgh,'CData');

myMat(2:end) = myMat(1:(end-1));
myMat(1) = rand(1);

generate_newdata = sin(myMat); 
return(myMat);


set(imgh,'CData',myMat);
drawnow;
set(obj,'UserData',imgh);
```

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

A function in MATLAB is defined as follows:

```
function [var_out] = fun_name(var_in)
   % enter your code here
end
```

"*When MATLAB reaches a return statement, it does not just exit the loop; it exits the script or function and returns control to the invoking function or command prompt.*"

Are you sure you are using MATLAB?